# htaccess - What's wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]*)/([a-z\-]*)/?([\w\d\=\:\,_-]*)?/?([a-z0-9\-]*)?/?$   $1.php?act=$2&cat=$3&sub=$4 [QSA,L]
```

It works with many URLs:

- users/manage/
- system/payments/
- system/payments/n=20:o=paid_time:s=DESC
- stores/themes/
- **stores/theme/n=20:o=created_time:s=DESC**

But failed with this URL:

- stores/themes/n=20:o=created_time:s=DESC

It's wrong with 1 addition 's' only.

Please help me with this, many thanks

Comment: The htaccess seems ok. You can test it here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=09932d6d-ce01-5901-81df-3af23573bf6c There must be some other error. Maybe in your app

Comment: please show us all your rules

Comment: thank you so much, I have a folder with stores, solved